# No column name was specified for column 2 of 't'

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have this query, but its not working

```
select t.ACCOUNT_ID 
from 
    (select   
         a.ACCOUNT_ID, count(a.ACCOUNT_ID)  
     from 
         EMPLOYER a, EMPLOYER b
     where 
         a.main_id = b.main_id 
     group by 
         a.MAIN_ID, a.account_id
     having 
        count(a.account_id) > 1) t
```

I am trying to find the duplicates and wanted to fetch the only ACCOUNT_ID from 
the subquery

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    select t.ACCOUNT_ID from (select   
 a.ACCOUNT_ID,count(a.ACCOUNT_ID) as cnt
from EMPLOYER a,EMPLOYER b
 where a.main_id = b.main_id 
 group by a.MAIN_ID,a.account_id
 having count( a.account_id) > 1)t
```

If you're going to select from a subquery, you should name at least the first instances of each column.

Added `as cnt` after `COUNT(a.account_id)`